# nginx cache check with try_files

Tags: caching, nginx, lua

I have an image server that writes to a cache directory (it just uses the same path in the url request at present). I have confirmed that on the initial request (i.e. nothing in the cache), a new file is written however on following requests, `try_files` does not successfully find the file.

My `nginx.conf` is:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        # serve tiles if not in the cache
        location @image_server {
          content_by_lua_file "/Users/tim/work/chickpea/serve_image.lua";
        }

        # capture tile request e.g. /tile/l8/091080/rgb/20160924/10/938/597.jpg
        # regex named capture groups for each param
        location ~ ^/tile/(?<layer>[^/]+)/(?<pathrow>[^/]+)/(?<type>[^/]+)/(?<date>[^/]+)/(?<z>[^/]+)/(?<x>[^/]+)/(?<y>[^.]+) {
          root cache;
          set $cachepath "cache/$layer/$pathrow/$type/$date/$z/$x/$y.jpg";
          try_files $cachepath @image_server;
          add_header X-Static hit;
        }

        ..
```

I have confirmed that on a request of `/tile/l8/091080/rgb/20160924/10/938/597.jpg`, the `$cachepath` is `cache/l8/091080/rgb/20160924/10/938/597.jpg` and that the `597.jpg` is in the correct path. I have tried a $cachepath both with and without the leading `cache/` and neither seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

There were two changes required to make this work:

1. Make the `root` directive an absolute path, otherwise it was effectively `/usr/local/nginx/cache`
2. Add a leading forward slash to the `$cachepath` variable. As the root directive value and `$cachepath` are appended together to determine the complete filepath.